# Crystal Reports - Bar chart - count of items in join table vs field in main table, on change of other field in main table

Tags: join, crystal-reports, charts, count, average

The scenario is thus:

- listings table contains ID, views, featured (0 or 1).
- applications table contains applications
- listings left-outer-joins applications on listings.id=application.listing_id

All fairly straightforward so far.

I am trying to make a bar chart which contains a comparison between standard (listings.featured=0) and featured (listings.featured=1) items. I want the applications per view (ie count of applications / sum of listings.views for all the listings in that category) for standard and the same for featured, with the two items featuring in a chart with a bar for each. The chart is in the report footer and should thus have access to the full data set.

- I therefore have the Chart Expert data -> On change of set to featured. This works.
- The problem is that the averages come up all out of whack.

I have tried:

- a variety of weighted averages
- formulae such as

  - count({cr_applications.id})/{cr_listings.views}
  - count({cr_applications.id})/sum({cr_listings.views})

If it helps, the SQL query which will get the correct output is:

```
SELECT 
    l.featured, 
    count(l.id) job_count,
    sum(l.views) total_views,
    avg(l.views) avg_views, 
    count(a.id) app_count, 
    count(a.id)/count(l.id) apps_per_job,
    count(a.id)/sum(l.views) apps_per_view
FROM
    listings l
LEFT JOIN 
     applications a ON l.id = a.listing_id
GROUP BY l.featured
```

I'm pretty stumped as Crystal reports is getting the maths totally wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a grouping on the listing.featured field then a simple formula field:

```
distinctcount({applicant.applicant_id}, {listing.featured})
/
distinctcount({listing.listing_id}, {listing.featured})
```

[image]

I have uploaded the report for you to examine (with data) here: http://snk.to/f-czjaxeam